# Number to Words in Java

Tags: java, bluej

I am struggling while doing this programme on BlueJ. Here is my code:

```
public class NumberToWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Number: ");
        int value = In.nextInt();
        int onesDigit;
        int tensDigit;
        String [] ones = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
            "eleven", "tweleve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};

        String [] tens = {"", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};

        String [] hundreds = {"one hundred", "two hundred", "three hundred", "four hundred", "five hundred", 
            "six hundred", "seven hundred", "eight hundred", "nine hundred" }; 
  while(value != -1)
 {
   if (value < 20)
    {

        String result = ones[value];
        System.out.println("" + result);
        value = In.nextInt();
    }
   if (value > 20 && value < 100)
    {
        tensDigit = value/10;
        onesDigit = value%10;
        System.out.print("" + ones[onesDigit] + " " + tens[tensDigit]);
        value = In.nextInt();

    }
 }

}    
}
```

So my problem is when I executed this it only appears word "Number" on my screen once when I entered the first number. For example:
Number: 1 => one and
2 => two
Now I want "Number: 2" will print out 2. Can someone have a look if anything is wrong with my code. Thanks!

Comment: just have a simple hashmap to do a mapping from the word to the actual number that you have encountered.

Comment: I'm sorry can you explain more please. I don't understand. I want to printout the word "Number" every time I enter a new number. Thank you!

Comment: your system.out.println("Number") is only executed once. if you want it to appear in front of every number, put it in the loop. Sorry for the confusion previously. It seems that I have misunderstood your problem

Comment: Hi I tried to insert my output inside the loop but it doesn't seem right. Do you have any idea? The problem is the word "Number" will appear before the word. For example: Number: 1 => Number: one

Answer (score -1):

The following code should help you to get desired output:

```
    public class NumberToWords  {
        public static void main(String[] args) {



            int onesDigit;
            int tensDigit;
            String [] ones = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten",
                "eleven", "tweleve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};

            String [] tens = {"", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};

            String [] hundreds = {"one hundred", "two hundred", "three hundred", "four hundred", "five hundred", 
                "six hundred", "seven hundred", "eight hundred", "nine hundred" };
            System.out.print("Number: ");
          int value = In.nextInt();
      while(value != -1)
     {

       if (value < 20)
        {

            String result = ones[value];
            System.out.println("" + result);
            System.out.print("Number: ");
            value = In.nextInt();
        }
       if (value > 20 && value < 100)
        {
            tensDigit = value/10;
            onesDigit = value%10;
            System.out.print("" + ones[onesDigit] + " " + tens[tensDigit]);
            System.out.print("Number: ");
            value = In.nextInt();

        }
     }

    }    
    }
```

Comment: How is anyone supposed to learn to program if someone else does their homework for them? The assignment was given in order to teach the student, and they learn nothing if you do their work for them except how to copy/paste code from other people, which results in their getting a degree they didn't earn and later a job they aren't qualified to do.